# Which versions of Windows 7 include Drive Manager?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

In an answer to a question I asked about mounting Virtual PC images, Philippe suggested using “drive manager” in Windows 7 to mount a .VHD file.

- [How do I convert a .vhd disk image to work with VMWare Fusion 2?](https://superuser.com/questions/48968/how-do-i-convert-a-vhd-disk-image-to-work-with-vmware/48970#48970)

Is “Drive Manager” available in all versions of Windows 7? Or do I need Ultimate Xtreme Enterprise 7 Edition 7 Pro.

Am I even correct in calling it “Drive Manager”? I’ve tried Googling a bit, but I couldn’t seem to find any references to a Windows 7 feature called that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Computer Management by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Maintenance, clicking Administrative Tools, and then double-clicking Computer Management. If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. In the Navigation pane, under Storage, click Disk Management.
3. Use the Menu at the top to attach a VHD.

Comment: “System and Security”, as opposed to “System and Maintenance”, on my machine. (I’m on Home Premium.)

Comment: And it’s specifically the “Action” menu in step 3.

Answer (score 3):

If by "Drive Manager" he meant the "Disk Management" MMC snap-in, then yes.  It's included in all versions of Windows 7 (and previous versions of Windows as well).

Click Start, type diskmgmt.msc, hit enter.