# Use Microsofts official Internet Explorer Virtual PC testing images in VMWare on OSX

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a .vhd disk image to work with VMWare Fusion 2?](https://superuser.com/questions/48968/how-do-i-convert-a-vhd-disk-image-to-work-with-vmware-fusion-2)

Is there a way to use [Microsofts official Internet Explorer Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) testing images in VMWare on OSX